# MongoDB subtext search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like

```
{
    City : "CityName11",
    State : "StateName1"
},
{
    City : "CityName2",
    State : "StateName2"
},{
    City : "CityName3",
    State : "StateName3"
}
```

Now on City field I have text index, I want to search using `"ci"`, and it should return all result which contains that phrase. I have tried with  `$search: "\"Ci\""` and seems that it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Text indexes do not work very well ( basically they do not work at all ) with things that are not actually "whole words".

For you type of serach you need to use a [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) instead:

```js
db.collection.find({ "City": { "$regex": "ci", "$options": "i" } })
```

And prefereably anchored to the start of the string and without the "case insensitive" option, which allows the use of an index ( a regular index ):

```js
db.collection.find({ "City": { "$regex": "^Ci" } })
```

Comment: Thanks @blakes-seven! your answer makes sense, but I need a query for auto-complete functionality, so I can't put "case insensitive" options since it is a predefined collection for address, is there any better way to search?

Comment: @AnkitSarkar There is not really any better way to do this. A text search will only work with a reasonably recognized word, so something as short will not match anything. A case insentive regex, even if also anchored will still need to scan the entire index. You can always do something like `^ci|Ci|CI|cI`, but again you still need the anchor or the entire index is scanned. And of course you can always split the content into unique word tokens within an array in lowercase yourself, then the case sesitivity is not an issue.